# Change color when changing directory

Tags: zsh, colors, cd-command

I have two folders called `Documents` and `Downloads`. In `zsh`, when I type

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

the color of `Documents` change from white to (hard to read) gray. How can I turn off this color change or control the color it is changed to?

[Here's my `.zshrc`](http://pastebin.com/W4RHwQSs)

The problem lies in this line here, where I change the coloring:

```
PS1="%F{$colorUser}%n%{$reset_color%}@%F{$colorServer}%m %{$reset_color%}: %F{$colorPath}%~%{$reset_color%} $ "
```

The variables are simply numbers, e.g. `$colorUser=196`, `$colorServer=202`, `$colorPath=44`.\

Comment: Paste your `.zshrc`...

Comment: @jasonwryan Edited my question.

Comment: Ugh: OMZ. Sorry, can't help with that ratmangle...

Comment: @jasonwryan What do you mean by ratmangle? It's mostly a fresh install from `oh-my-zsh`.

Comment: I mean OMZ is a ratmangle. Does the behaviour persist if you disable it? I certainly can't reproduce on my Zsh.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for the heads up. Indeed, I haven't heard the word "ratmangle" before. Even my dictionary turned up with nothing. So I googled for it and I found it might be a synonym for OMZ. So I figured people are unhappy with it. Since I'm new to `zsh`, I simply took their/your word for granted and removed everything from OMZ. I still have the same problem though. It has something to do with the way I set the `PS1` variable. I updated the link to my `.zshrc` and also my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using e.g. `%F{202}`, I can use `%{$fg[red]%}`. This fixes the problem. However, I'm reduced to only use 16 colors instead of 256 colors. It seems to me like this is a bug in `zsh`.